# Implementing AnimationListener abstract methods

Tags: java, android, animation

I'm learning Android Dev using Sam's Teach Yourself Android Application Development in 24 hours and i came across a code below. I'm also relatively new to Java but i understand pretty well the basics but i don't understand how a onAnimationEnd() can be implemented inside as a parameter??? Can someone explain what's going on and how is this a valid argument (syntax) for the setAnimationListener method?

```
fade2.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    // The animation has ended, transition to the Main Menu screen
        startActivity(new Intent(QuizSplashActivity.this, QuizMenuActivity.class));
        QuizSplashActivity.this.finish();
    }

    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    }

    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
       }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

That's called an [anonymous inner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) and one of Java's most useful features, especially for listeners. (The linked article has more code examples.)

Basically, it's a shorthand syntax for creating a new class which implements the `AnimationListener` interface. The class has no name, which is why it's called an "anonymous" class. You're able to define all three methods of the interface inline, within the method call. And inside the anonymous inner class, you can access fields, methods and local variables from the containing class and method.

You might also want to read through the discussion on [Android and Java - use of Runnable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052158/android-and-java-use-of-runnable/11052436#11052436).

Comment: Thanks @cogentapps. This concept sounds similar to the lambda function in python for me. So it makes lots of sense.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a parameter.  It looks like one coming from a newbie perspective, but it is an interface and the method that has to be implemented is `onAnimationEnd`.  If you look at an `onClickListener` it is the same principle.  You are required to implement the `onClick` method immediately.  The method that is being called is also called an anonymous method.  It is a method without a name.  You will also see these methods in a lot of places in Java too.

Comment: I haven't come across the 'onClickeListener' yet. But when i do i will know!